# How can I merge a map into values.yaml wit yq

Tags: bash, yaml, yq

I am trying to create a multiple map in a values.yaml as follows.

```
FILES=$(ls -1 | grep "values-.*.yaml") 
for i in $FILES; do
   yq e '.applications *= {
            "'$i'":{
               "enabled":"true",
               "destination":{
                  "namespace":"x",
                  "server":"wwww"
               },
               "source":{
                  "chart":"'$i'"
               }
            }
         }' values.yaml
done
```

and this is the next output:

**Error: Cannot multiply !!null with !!map**

The yaml should look like this:

```
applications:
  a:
    enabled: "true"
    destination:
      namespace: x
      server: wwww
    source:
      chart: a
  b:
    enabled: "true"
    destination:
      namespace: x
      server: wwww
    source:
      chart: b
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try: `files=(values-.*.yaml); for i in "${files[@]}"; ...; done` , untested though.

Comment: Same error.. I don't know how yq work with multiple maps

Answer (score 1):

With your code you get the error when the file `values.yaml` is empty at the beginning

```yaml
applications:
```

Instead use this and the error `Cannot multiply !!null with !!map` disappears:

```yaml
applications: {}
```

Apart from that, your code has some problems.
I would like to suggest passing the filename to `yq` as a parameter and accessing it within the code with `strenv`

```bash
FILES=$(ls -1 | grep "values-.*.yaml")
for i in $FILES; do
  file="$i" yq '.applications *=
    {strenv(file): {
       "enabled":"true",
       "destination": {
          "namespace":"x",
          "server":"www"
       },
       "source": {
          "chart": strenv(file)
       }
    }
  }' values.yaml
done
```

This code breaks, if a file name contains whitespaces, e.g. `values-3. gap.yaml`.
To address this issue think about using `find ... exec` instead of a `for` loop.

Comment: I have solved it:

https://gitlab.com/AndreCbrera/scripts/-/blob/main/yq.sh

but thanks a lot !